# PDF page flip (open source)

Tags: flash

I'm doing a web site for a client, and he requested a PDF page flip on it.
I've been looking for sometime, but can't quite find anything appropriate.

I have the URLs to PDFs in my database, and I think the simplest way to implement this would be to just pass the URL to the PDF through HTML so it dynamically opens any PDF from the DB.

Deas anybody have any good free PDF page flip engine?
Thanks in advance for any input!

Andrej

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking at this kind of stuff recently, but finally did not actually start the project. So these I have not really tried, but they did look among the best free solutions: http://www.flashpageflip.com/FreeFPF.asp ,which his free(has php and asp based pro versions, too) for commercial, but forces a tiny txt url link at bottom left (in some projects this does not really matter) , and this other one, not allowed in commercial projects : http://www.megazine3.de

Besides that, there are many great services that even host for you the pdf and the conversion is automatically made by them, and served.

Depending on bandwidth, time, etc, I'd go for just using a free converter like mentioned, grab the resulting swf files, host the swfs my self, embedding with the typical html tags. Probably would not be much complex to do some scripting in python, or other language, to automate it, if it's a lot of PDFs.

EDIT: Sorry, did not pay attention to the "open source" requirement. Only Megazine, of the mentioned.

Comment: Well te open source itself is not a requirement.. just that it's free... thanks for the anwser!

Comment: One point here, most of these solutions (including this one) don't support PDF files, you'll need to split them into individual images. There are some paid hosted services that allow you to use PDFs, but i've not seen anything installable.

Comment: You mean they don't support it fully, I guess. It depends on each one's needs.. Anyway, other options (did not finally start the project, as I mentioned) that "might" work: using pdf2swf (but output "one frame per page", not sure what it means). Or if installable means in server, you might build a bit more complex workflow setting  up on server imagemagick (not sure if you'd need ghostscript, too) to dynamically do the conversion. Looks like all this stuff better be proccessed offline, then upload. Anyway, hoping to have been of help to some needs, here. :)links: swftools.org , imagemagick.org

Comment: FINALLY got it working with megazine, itextsharp, nunint and ghostscriptsharp frameworks...  the result is quite nice! ;) thanks everybody for the help!

Comment: Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at this JavaScript + HTML5 plugin (http://www.turnjs.com). Although it's not Flash it may be a good alternative, especially seeing as this question is 3 years old.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the following page flipping tools：
1. **Issuu**: an online open source service can turn uploaded PDF into a page flipping book.
2. **Page Flip flap**: A free online tool that can accept PDF and create page flippable books
3. **Kvisoft flipbook maker**: a desktop shareware for making page flipping books out of PDF, Office documents and images.